# Why can I write a char basic_fstream into an int array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I don't understand how the following code can work.

```
void read(int *);
int numbers[10];
fstream myfile;

int main() {
    myfile.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    read(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }
}

void read(int *z) {
    // is my understanding correct that *z is an pointer to the first element of the array?
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        myfile >> *z++; // why can write characters into an int array?
    }
}
```

**my_file** has

```
 basic_fstream<char>
```

as datatype.

however in the read function, it's values are written into an int array.

Comment: You've never seen `std::cin >> n;`, where `n` is an `int`?

Comment: Really puzzled what you are confused about. Of course you can read integers from an fstream (and put them in a int array).

Comment: The char in `basic_fstream<char>` means that the stream reads `char` data (as opposed to say `wchar_t`) but it doesn't mean that it can't turn those `char` into integers, floating points, strings, etc. etc.

Comment: The streams have lots of [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) overloads for different types. Like `int`.

Comment: For the same reason that you can write `cout << numbers[i]` when the type of `std::cout` is `basic_ostream<char>`. The template argument gives the type of the data in the underlying stream; the stream operators (`<<` and `>>`) do the necessary translations between text and values. Silly example: what value does "1234" represent? It's four characters, but we read it as an integer.